# NoClassDefFoundError exception when using ConcurrentLinkedHashMap 1.4 on Android 2.2

Tags: android

I'm using the latest version of [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/) as a cache system. It works very fine on android 4+. But when I run the app on my old HTC legend (Android 2.2) it stops with NoClassDefFoundError Exception. I didn't test it with 2.3 or 3.

As I searched the exception relates to a class that is present at compile time but absent during run time. But I don't know why it works fine on android 4 but not 2.2. Maybe it relates to android java coding style? any suggestion is appreciated.

EDIT ---------------------

I just used version 1.2 of ConcurrentLinkedHashMap instead of 1.4. It works fine. But why doesn't version 1.4 works?

EDIT 2 ------------------

The exception is thrown for an internal class of ConcurrentLinkedHashMap which is LinkedDeque. Not an external library. And By the way I compile the code against android 2.2 SDK not 4. So if if it requires any library of android 4 it must not be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LinkedDeque` class depends on [`Deque`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Deque.html) which is only available on Android since API Level 9 (Android 2.3).

By the way, your class is really overkill and on Android you should use [`LruCache`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html) instead (included in the support library, works on Android 1.6 and above).

Comment: why do you mean by overkill?

Comment: Thank you, I migrated to LruCache.

Comment: By overkill I mean it's a complex implementation and I don't think you will notice any actual performance improvement over LruCache on an Android phone. LruCache is also synchronized so can be shared between threads.

Answer (score 1):

> As I searched the exception relates to a class that is present at compile time but absent during run time. But I don't know why it works fine on android 4 but not 2.2.

You already answered that question yourself -> it does not work on 2.2 because there's no library that is needed. You need to check stacktrace from crash to see what lib exactly it is missing.

Comment: I know that and have already done checking the stacktrace. The exception is thrown for an internal class of ConcurrentLinkedHashMap. I added this to my question.